# Ubuntu Wordpress Installation

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I am trying to download Wordpress on Ubuntu but I seem to be getting this message all the time:

```
 web2@web2-Advent-DT3411:~$ cd ~/wordpress
 web2@web2-Advent-DT3411:~/wordpress$ cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php
 cp: cannot create regular file ‘wp-config.php’: Permission denied
```

Is it because I don't have permissions to create or edit files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

please try this one.

give permission your folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/your folder name
```

OR

Copy your wp-config-sample.php file and rename it to wp-config.php and

change your username,database name,password,and host.

like this:------

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: This is just for example to give his folder permission.Give the permission 755 for folder.

Comment: It's recursive, so everything inside (including the WP installation) would get 777.

Answer (score -1):

I got wordpress installed sucessfully on my ubuntu 14.04 by following only 3 below instructions:

1.Install xampp from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
[image]

Run downloaded file by using command =>

local_ubuntu$ sudo chmod 777 xampp-linux-x64-7.0.13-1-installer.run

local_ubuntu$ ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.13-1-installer.run

Installer will pop-up then install .

2.Then similarly download wordpress from https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer

[image]

Run the downloaded Wordpress file =>

local_ubuntu$ sudo chmod 777 bitnami-wordpress-4.7.1-0-linux-x64-installer.run

local_ubuntu$ ./bitnami-wordpress-4.7.1-0-linux-x64-installer.run

Installer pop-up then I installed in /opt/lamp/htdocs/WordPress.

3.a.)From XAMPP screen -->Start all Services.

b.)Go to browser and in address bar , type ->localhost:8080/wordpress.

That's all done .....